# How to test an editor add-on for Google Docs with the new Apps Script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, add-on

I'm trying to test a simple add-on for Google Docs that I've made but it seems that [this page of documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#create_a_test_configuration) is related to the legacy Apps Script editor, and I cannot find out how to do with the new Apps Script editor.

1. I have read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905353/creating-and-testing-an-add-on-for-google-sheets-in-the-new-script-editor), but he's trying to deploy a Workspace add-on (which is different to editor add-on)
2. I know that I could simply copy-paste my code into an Apps Script directly bound to a Google Docs, but that's not what I want, I really want my add-on code in its own, independant, Apps Script project.
3. My Apps Script project is linked to a proper GCP project (with billing and oauth consent screen ok)

My code, if it helps

```js
const PASS = "PASSPHRASE";

function decrypt(text) {
  var cipher = new cCryptoGS.Cipher(PASS, 'aes');
  return cipher.decrypt(text)
}

function encrypt(text) {
  var cipher = new cCryptoGS.Cipher(PASS, 'aes');
  return cipher.encrypt(text)
}

function decryptDocument() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
  return paragraphs.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous + "\n" + decrypt(current.getText());
  }, ""); 
}

function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Décodeur')
      .addItem('Lancer le décodeur', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('decoder')
      .setTitle('Décodeur');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="decrypt()">Décoder le contenu</button>
    <div id="decodedText">
      </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var running = false;

    function onSuccess(decodedText) {
      running = false;
      document.getElementById("decodedText").innerHTML = decodedText;
    }

    function onFailure(e) {
      running = false;
      console.error(e);
    }

    function cleanDiv() {
      document.getElementById("decodedText").innerHTML = "";
    }

    function decrypt() {
      running = true;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .decryptDocument();
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

```json
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "cCryptoGS",
        "version": "4",
        "libraryId": "1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It looks that you missed this part: "Note: You must use the legacy editor to test Editor Add-ons. To switch from the new editor to the legacy editor, click Use legacy editor at the top of the editor screen."

Comment: god I hate those blue background notes, I never see them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to thoroughly test an editor add-on is by publishing by using the Google Workspace SDK.

If you want to use "Test as add-on" feature of the Google Apps Script you have to use the legacy editor. This might be fine to test some features like an **onOpen simple trigger**  but not to test other features like **installable triggers**.

As apparently your editor add-on is not using installable triggers and other features that can't be tested with "Test as add-on" it's very likely that it will be good enough to test the simple triggers of your add-on.

P.S. Your add-on is missing the `onInstall` simple trigger that usually is used to call the `onOpen` trigger when the add-on is installed from an opened document.

Related

- [Installable Trigger Failing with Test Add-On](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29721609/1595451)
- [Is "Test as add-on" for Google sheets editor add-ons broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67852563/1595451)
- [Testing Google Sheet Addon Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69774457/1595451)